# Using WITH in VBA to refresh Excel 2016 PivotTable fails?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, with-statement

This code works:

```
Activesheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.RefreshTable
```

This code does not, returning error msg "Object doesn't support this property or method":

```
With Activesheet
   .PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.RefreshTable
End With
```

Why?

Comment: `PivotCache.RefreshTable` looks off, seems like the [`RefreshTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivottable.refreshtable) is a method of a `PivotTable`.

Comment: Those 2 code pieces are identically, it's just a slightly different syntax. The `PivotCache` object has no method `RefreshTable` (it has, however, a method `Refresh`) - but that means that both code pieces throw the same error.

Comment: remarkable, because if one uses the XL "Record Macro" while refreshing a PivotTable manually, the recorded VBA includes the PivotCache term.

Comment: When I recorded a macro, the resulting code was `.PivotCache.Refresh`, which is valid. `.PivotCache.RefreshTable` is definitely not though.

Comment: Deleting my answer and voting to close as a typo / not reproducible.